# Drivers for Logitech QuickCam Orbit AF: Any third-party options?

Tags: webcam, driver

I have a lovely USB webcam, namely the [QuickCam® Orbit AF](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/webcam-communications/webcams/devices/3480). It's the type of webcam one often sees at Customs checkpoints at airports around the world. It also looks a bit like HAL.

[image: HAL]

The problem is that it's only fully supported under Windows. I'm after a third-party solution because:

> Your Logitech camera must be UVC
>   (Universal Video Class) compliant in
>   order to be used on your Mac OS 10.4.9
>   and above computer. *These standard UVC
>   drivers are provided by the Operating
>   System and will only provide minimal
>   camera support.*
>
> [...]
>
> **NOTE:** With the exception of the
>   QuickCam Vision Pro for Mac and the HD
>   Pro Webcam C910, all other UVC cameras
>   are not officially supported on the
>   Mac and some features or application
>   support may not work.

I wonder if someone can point towards a third-party driver that'll make this thing run like it does on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd try would be [Macam](http://webcam-osx.sourceforge.net/). Your camera is listed as 'it depends (UVC)' on the [supported list](http://webcam-osx.sourceforge.net/cameras/index.php), which suggests it's getting most of its functionality from the built-in UVC driver anyway. But it's free, so you've nothing to lose by trying it...

EDIT: Scratch that. The [details page](http://webcam-osx.sourceforge.net/cameras/camera.php?id=681) for your camera says it doesn't yet work with Macam at all, only with the built-in UVC driver.

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying anyway Calum. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody finally made a little app that supports the pan and tilt movement for the Logitech quickcam orbit sphere AF for OS X

Zoom is not (yet) supported

https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/orbit-command/id666312129?l=en&mt=12

Costs you €10